# Storing dictionary values in a list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary in the following format:

```
d = { 'x' : [1,2], 'y' : [1,3,4], 'z' : [1,1] }
```

And I am trying to append the values of 'd' to a list in the following format:

```
lst = [1,2,1,3,4,1,1]
```

Hence, 'lst' contains all the values of the dictionary 'd'.

My code :-

```
 lst = [value for v in d.values()]
```

But this does not work.

Any suggestions as to how I can put these values in a list?

Thank you.

Comment: `[v for l in d.values() for v in l]`? Your attempt is trying to reference a variable that doesn't exist, so its failure shouldn't surprise you! Note that dictionaries don't guarantee order, so `[1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1] ` isn't necessarily the output you'll get.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> lst = [item for v in d.values() for item in v]
```

Comment: works! Thank you so much

Comment: @Luke You're welcome.